# Blank screen after kernel upgrade 3.19.0-25 to 3.19.0.80

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, kernel, screen

Ubuntu version 14.04.1. This kernel has been downloaded and waiting for a restart. The restart happened tonight. The screen goes black during boot and the monitor goes into power saving mode.

This happened before during an attempted distribution upgrade to 16 but I figured it was just a borked install and reinstalled 14. This time, it was just a kernel upgrade so I made grub boot to the original kernel (3.19.0-25) and the screen comes up fine, just as it did before.

My search turned up that there was an issue during the upgrade to 3.19.0-26 that people had but this was apparently fixed and so should not have affected me. (Checking back, the upgrade that caused me problems was to Ubuntu 16.04.1 and kernel 3.19.0-68)

Hardware is an Intel Nuc. I believe that's Intel graphics.

Oh, additionally, alt-Fx to select consoles does not work with this.

Answer (score 0):

I kept looking. I found a suggestion to remove "splash" from /etc/default/grub but that was not there. Tried adding "quiet" and that didn't help.

In the end, the line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2332511

Has allowed the system to boot as before. While this is a workaround, I would still like to see a proper solution.